Encoding problem when migrating postgresql database tables to models.py django
When performing table migration
python manage.py inspectdb > example/models.py


all Cyrillic strings are transposed as a set of unknown characters:
'id_шёїюф ∙хую'
Encoding of the database server as well as python script is UTF-8.
Is there any way to solve this problem?
I tried
show server_encoding;

and got UTF8, tried
set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8


Also, I added
'OPTIONS': {
            'client_encoding': 'UTF8',
        }

into settings.py.
All aforementioned methods didn't help and problem is still existing.
I use psycopg package.

The important factor is the PostgreSQL client encoding.

when SHOW client_encoding; executed, it shows UTF8 @LaurenzAlbe

I guess it depends on what manage.py is doing.

I think it might be because the collation and ctype are Russian_Russia.1251 @LaurenzAlbe

No, these should have no influence.

Do you think it's related to manage.py, even if it hasn't been changed yet? @LaurenzAlbe

I don't know what manage.py is, so I find it hard to say. Perhaps the resulting file is just fine, and it is your Windows text editor that cannot display UTF-8 properly.

I think it's everything okay with my text editor, because this problem also affects the uploading of table and column names in models.py after python manage.py inspectdb > example/models.py. Maybe I should just replace the Cyrillic characters in the column and table names. @LaurenzAlbe

Solved the problem this way:
I left the database in English, and when migrating entities to Django, renamed the model fields to Cyrillic, specifying db_name in models.py. After that everything is displayed correctly in both the application and the database
